# PHP Authenticate HTTP Message

Tags: php, security, http

I have following Situation,
Server A sends some data (HTML form) to server B, B then does some DB queries and stuff (irrelevant) and sends "Confirmed" or "not confirmed" back to A (via fsock, to an address that is deliverd as an hidden field in the form ). But it is possible to fake this answer, so how can i ensure ( on A side ) that the answer is real?
I am looking for an safe aproach easier than GPG for example...
Thanks!

Comment: How safe do you need it to be? HTTP basic auth is extraordinarily easy to implement. Beyond that, you can get into certificate-based authentication and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a client certificate for HTTPS requests from Server A, and only allow access to Server B if the request comes from a valid certificate.

There are [plenty of tutorials](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500) out there on the interwebs.